# Multiple Brands Versions Management with Jira

Tags: version, jira

Our firm provide a web based product which is deployed onto multiple brands (customers) in a different data centers. Due to regulation concern we cannot multi-tenant architecture with our services.

Our code base is identical for all brands and we deploy each version to all brands in a lag of few hours up to a week (i.e we may deploy version V to brand A at 8:00AM, to brand B at 10:00AM and to brand C a week later).

We use Jira OnDemand as our task management system. The problem I'm trying to solve is that Jira supports only one release date for a version but since we release each version multiple times we should know somehow what date each version was release on (besides of course using a spreadsheet).

I appreciate any idea that can make my life easier.

Thanks,

Gil

Answer (score 0):

I would start by imagining how you would do it with a spreadsheet. For the same version name V you would have a column named something like "Deployment Date and Time". I'd do the same in JIRA - create a custom Date and Time picker field and when a specific customer is updated, set the custom field to the date and time.

Comment: Using custom fields in that fashion means I have to manage the deployment on a story/bug level since. In order to use a workflow in Jira which is similar to the spreadsheet one, I should have multiple tuples of brand and release date for each version

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to create multiple versions for the different brands and have those multiple versions assigned to a single Jira item. The versions can then be released independently. So for example my version list would look like this:

Brand1-0.9
Brand1-1.0
Brand2-0.9
Brand2-1.0
Brand3-0.9
Brand3-1.0

This is a bit of effort, but I think it should solve your problem. It would also keep you flexible, different release dates for different brands are no problem this way.